# Morph an OpenGL sphere

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, computer-vision

This is about how to create an OpenGL irregular sphere. I've searched the web, but all the documents are telling how to create a regular sphere.

The effect I need is to simulate a bubble, and when the user touch the bubble, it should act on the touch, and the sphere bubble should change its shape on the touch position. Say, concave the touch part.

I can't figure out a feasible way to do this kind of simulation. Should I change the vertex  position of touch part ? Or can I use a shader to implement this effect ?

At the same time, I don't know how can simulate the concave realistically, is there any math procedure to describe such a process ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll want to use a geodesic-style sphere rather than one create via lat / long vertices. That will deform more predictably.

From there, there are several ways to do it. One way I could think of would be to create graph where each node indexes into a vertex in your mesh, and each node contains links to its neighbors. Then, when a vertex is pressed, it can "pull" its neighbors in with it. A cheap way would be to simply relocate the pressed vertex and then pull neighbors toward the new position, maintaining the original distance (very simple vector math). Then, repeat for those neighbors until the distance each neighbor is pulled reaches a sufficiently small threshold.

Once complete, the mesh will likely have to be reuploaded to GPU.

Comment: May I know what's a geodesic-style sphere ?

Comment: Well, some spheres are basically a grid of vertices wrapped into a sphere. This produces many vertices at the poles, and fewer vertices at the equator. A geodesic sphere has an even distribution of vertices around its surface.

Answer (score 1):

When I morph an object I just use an animation from the start vertex to the end vertex. The animation can have about 200 frames or so. I'm not sure how I can caclculate the steps from the start vertex to the end vertex. Maybe there is some trigonomic function? In your example I would create a sphere with the button and use it as a target frame. I'm not sure how a shader can help you here.

Comment: So, you mean to create a new 3D model to present the state of touched bubble. But, there are two problems left: 1. How it the final object shape on the touch point ? I need a math procedure to generate it. 2. The user can touch any position of the bubble, how can I use one model to fit that ?